# Trying to display api data from an XHR request in handlebars

Tags: ember.js

I'm pulling in a list of groups from an api to my Ember app with an XHR request. I'm trying to display that list in the groups/index.hbs template. In the template I have:

```
<h1>GROUPS INDEX</h1>
{{#each group in controller}}
  {{ group.name }}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed <(generated groups.index controller):ember226>
```

The array of objects is loading fine. I just cant display them in handlebars.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

groups_route.js.coffee

```
Mdm.GroupsRoute = Ember.Route.extend(model: ->
  Mdm.Group.all()
)
```

router.js.coffee

```
Mdm.Router.map ->
  @resource 'groups', ->
    @resource 'group', path: ':group_id'

Mdm.Router.reopen
  location: 'history'
```

group.js.coffee

```
Mdm.Group = Ember.Object.extend()

Mdm.Group.reopenClass
  all: ->
    Mdm.ajax(
      url: Mdm.apiUrl('/groups')
    ).then (data) ->
      console.log data
      groups = []
      for group in data.response
        groups.addObject(Mdm.Group.create(group))
      console.log(groups)
      groups
```

Comment: How does the controller your looping over look like?

Comment: Its just using the auto generated controller.

Comment: Have you tried defining it explicitly like `App.GroupsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();`?

Comment: I did. I get the same error.

Comment: hmmm, how does your parent template looks like that's rendering the groups.index into it's outlet?

Comment: just: 
<h1>Application.hbs</h1>
{{outlet}}

Do you think something like this is necessary? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

Comment: try to remove the `{{outlet}}` definition inside your `groups.index` template...

Comment: No change. And by the way, thank you for your time. What exactly does it mean by "an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array"?

Comment: I've seen people having this issue related to nested `{{#each}}` loops, maybe it would be helpful to see your routes definitions

Comment: I added my routes to my original question.

Comment: I also added the group model above.

Comment: one more try :) since you have nested resources, have you tried renaming your groups route to `Mdm.GroupsIndexRoute`?

Comment: Success! So should my template for individual groups be routed from GroupsShowRoute and groups/show.hbs?

Thanks so much!

Comment: exactly, If the additional routes are nested inside your groups resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the comments and for anyone else stumbling upon this error, I'll post an answer.

So the solution seams to be to rename your route to:

```
Mdm.GroupsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(model: ->
  Mdm.Group.all()
)
```

Glad I could help :)